# Goroutines inside for loop returns different values

Tags: go, concurrency

i'm trying to practise go routines.
what am i missing here? this code returned me a different array results.

```
func goRoutinesSearch(body string, keywords []string) {
     lowerBody := strings.ToLower(body)
     var matched []string
     var wg sync.WaitGroup
     wg.Add(len(keywords))
     for _, word := range keywords {
         go func(w string) {
             defer wg.Done()
             if strings.Contains(lowerBody, w) {
                 matched = append(matched, w)
             }
         }(word)
     }
     wg.Wait()
     fmt.Print(matched)
}
```

thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
matched = append(matched, w)
```

Is a [critical section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section) which is not [synchronized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion), resulting in a race condition. It's not an atomic operation. There are many different inter-leavings of the go routines that will result in different outputs, and is completely unpredictable with the potential to lose data.

The easiest way to make this [thread-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety) (safe for concurrent exeuction) is to synchronize access to `matched` with a [mutex](https://gobyexample.com/mutexes):

```
func goRoutinesSearch(body string, keywords []string) {
     lowerBody := strings.ToLower(body)
     var mutex = &sync.Mutex{}
     var matched []string
     var wg sync.WaitGroup
     wg.Add(len(keywords))
     for _, word := range keywords {
         go func(w string) {
             defer wg.Done()
             if strings.Contains(lowerBody, w) {
                 mutex.Lock()
                 matched = append(matched, w)
                 mutex.Unlock()
             }
         }(word)
     }
     wg.Wait()
     fmt.Print(matched)
}
```

The mutex ensures that only a single go routine is able to `append` to `matched` at any given time, so you'll never have overwriting appends.

---

**I think you may still have different array results depending on the order of execution of goroutines, but you won't potentially lose data now that it is synchronized.**

Comment: Thanks! you mean array with different order?

Comment: @ArielBelakhov yes exactly, even though it's "concurrently correct" now (protected from race conditions with the mutex), there's nothing guaranteeing the `matched` order will be the order they matches occur in `keywords`